# hot deploy an exploded webapp in embedded jetty 9.4.x

Tags: eclipse, jetty, war, embedded-jetty, contextpath

I have a web application in the form of exploded WAR file and wanted to (hot)deploy this directory as a web application with embedded jetty.

from the section : **Understanding the Default WebAppProvider** from [this documentation](https://docs.huihoo.com/jetty/the-definitive-reference/deployment-architecture.html#default-web-app-provider), I understood that it is possible to deploy a webapp in the form of directory.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:543)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:64)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:88)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ListenerHolder.doStart(ListenerHolder.java:73)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)

My code looks something like this :

```
            Server server = new Server(8888);
            ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();

            HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
            handlers.addHandler(contexts);
            handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
            server.setHandler(handlers);


            org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager deployer = new org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager();
            deployer.setContexts(contexts);

            WebAppProvider webapp_Provider = new WebAppProvider();

            webapp_Provider.setMonitoredDirName(/parent/directory/of/my/exploded/war/directory);

            webapp_Provider.setScanInterval(2); // how often to scan

            deployer.addAppProvider(webapp_Provider);
            server.addBean(deployer);

            server.start();
```

Also it would be helpful if anyone can suggest on how to keep a watch on this directory with jetty(9.4.x) so that jetty can honour the changes done in the web application and update them on the fly.

I find it tough to get relevant documentation for hot deployment with embedded jetty

looking forward for advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a hot deployment issue, but rather missing configurations to enable bytecode/annotation scanning and ServletContainerInitializer features.   Is there any other code you have for configuring Jetty that is missing from this question?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt this is the only piece of code that I have for configuring Jetty.
if it is so that I'm missing extra configurations, could you point me out to what am I missing to setup the jetty to deploy my webapp directory? Thanks.